# batch script permission grant for specific folders

Tags: batch-file, directory, icacls

I have a script that currently looks for all files/subfolders in directories named 'Avid MediaFiles' and grants full control permissions + outputs the results into a text file.

```
cd /d Y:\UserWorkspaces
FOR /D /r %%g in ("Avid MediaFiles*") DO icacls "%%g" /grant "Administrators":(OI)(CI)F /T >> Avid_Permissions_Fixed.txt
```

The only issue with it is that once it's running it fixes all files/folders regardless of their permission status, even the ones that have been fixed before. Ideally I'd like to add a condition in which it skips fixing the ones that already have full control permissions and change the ones that don't. Is that feasible just with batch script?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but will complicate the script quite a lot.
There shouldn't be a reason to check for the permission. If it's set, setting it again won't do any harm.
You can check for certain permission like this:

```
icacls . | find "Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)"
if errorlevel 1 echo Doesn't have this permission
```

but if it's not exactly as (OI)(CI)(F), you'll have false positive.

You will than have to get rid of `/T` and iterate each folder and file, if you don't want to go into much more difficult parsing of the whole icacls *.* /T output structure.

There is probably another way around your problem. Find out what exactly is happening.
If you don't need any specific permissions for specific files/folders in those folders, and if all files/folders have their inheritance turned on, then a simple
`FOR /D %%g in ("Y:\UserWorkspaces\Avid MediaFiles*") DO icacls %%g /reset /T`
should work. It will fix permissions for files moved in a folder from permission restricted location. It won't add any new permissions, but will remove any possible explicit ones.

For anything more complicated, I wouldn't bother nor recommend using Batch. PowerShell can do this quite effectively and without the risk of string parsing errors. Check all ACL in one loop, fix in another.

btw. There is no `for /D /r`. The /r is probably ignored.